# Retrieve heart rate with microsoft band

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, sdk, microsoft-band

I am currently developing an app in swift and i want to use the microsoft band with it. The only thing i want to do is include the SDK example of BandHeartRate that is included. The problem is that the SDK is in Objective-C and i don't know if i could use this code in my app.

I have tried the following:

1) Include the CoreBluetooth and Microsoft Band Framework in Linked Frameworks and Libraries
2) Create a bridging header that has: 
   #import < MicrosoftBandKit_iOS/MicrosoftBandKit_iOS.h >
3) Include the example code in my app (the .h and .m)

It seems that it can't access the framework so i don't know what to do in order to make it work. I just need the example code in objective-C to be included in my app (that is in swift)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you absolutely can incorporate the sdk in your app.  Add a bridging header (I'm on mobile) and the classes and methods will automatically be cast into swift types ( including autocomplete)

Answer (score 0):

I have created a Swift 2.1 (Xcode 7.2.1) Band Heart Rate sample based on the Microsoft Band Kit for iOS release from Dec. 22, 2015. Have a look at: https://github.com/mthistle/MicrosoftBandKit_iOS-Swift2.2/tree/master/BandSensor/BSwiftHeartRate

The sample follows the Microsoft released sample and I have included everything in a single repo so you can pull the entire Obj-C and Swift samples. At the moment I only have the Heart Rate sample converted but the other's should follow easily from that.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks! This helped me a lot!

Comment: Though it would be nice to include an entire iOS Swift based project here for reference that seems unreasonable for such an answer. The issue this person is having appears to be in multiple areas including project setup and code conversion from Swift 1/Obj-C to Swift 2.1. I am willing to post the code though if people think that would be better.